# How to tell if an image has a virus?

Tags: virus, spyware, whatsapp, image

I received (and opened) an image from Whatsapp. How can I know if this image contains a virus (spyware)?

Is it possible to send photos containing virus using Whatsapp Mod (unofficial versions of whatsapp)?

Comment: Welcome to the community. What indicators of compromise do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I haven't any indicators of compromize but i'm afraid this person (that has sent to me this image) will spy on me with a spyware

Comment: Then where does the assumption come from? That scenario is extremely unlikely by the way.

Comment: I no longer trust the person I was texting with

Comment: occam's razor says they probably just sent you an image. Is there any reason you think kit might have been a virus?

Comment: No, just the fact that I no longer trust the person who sent me the photo. I wanted to know if there is a way to know if there is spyware on my smartphone

Comment: Send suspicious files to virustotal.com. If you can send a photo, then you can send a photo that contains spyware, but unless there is something wrong with Whatsapp, the spyware won't do anything. It is impossible for us to know what your off-brand Whatsapp might be vulnerable to.

Comment: I downloaded the official version of whatsapp but I'm not sure if the person who sent me the photo has the official version of whatsapp. If he had a Whatsapp Mod could he send me spyware through the photos?

Comment: Regardless of whether the sender used a custom version to embed something, your *Official Version* will not execute it **by design**. Yes it's possible there is a zero-day exploit no one knows about in the *Official Version* but that would be worth a lot of money, burning such an expensive exploit to harass you is beyond unlikely.